# Change the encoding of every single .txt file in a folder and its subfolders

Tags: command-line, bash, files, encoding

I have a folder include many txt files and sub-folders which also contains many txt files.

I want to change all of the files' encoding automatically. Right now I know how to change one file using the command:

```
iconv -f gbk -t utf8 sample.txt > sample.wiki
```

I need the name of the file not changed and change its extension to .wiki. How can I achieve this automatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate though the `.txt` files, change encoding, save the output in `.wiki` file of the same name using `-o` option of `iconv` and if successful remove the relevant `.txt` file:

```
shopt -s globstar  ## Enables recursive glob matching
for f in **/*.txt; do
    iconv -f gbk -t utf8 -o "${f%.txt}".wiki "$f" && rm "$f"
done
```

**Caveat:**

If the input file is not in given source encoding or already in the target encoding, `iconv` will return true without doing any operation, hence the `.wiki` file will not be created and the `.txt` file will be removed.

To work around this you can save the STDOUT after conversion in a variable and if the variable is not-empty only then save the output in the `.wiki` file and remove the `txt` file:

```
shopt -s globstar  ## Enables recursive glob matching
for f in **/*.txt; do
    out="$(iconv -f gbk -t utf8 "$f")" 
    [[ -n $out ]] && echo "$out" >"${f%.txt}".wiki && rm "$f"
done
```

Comment: This really helps me, can't imagine to do this manually. I have about 200 files and this command line works just right! thanks for the nice answer.

Comment: @buzhidao Glad i could help :)

Comment: Neat trick with shell expansion and  `&&`.  Would `find` be faster? I  usually `-print0` with `find` , then pipe to `xargs` or `parallel`.